# Why is this AJAX callback not being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When I click the submit button in the following form, my jQuery GET function is called, but the callback is not. Any ideas?

```
<body>
<form id="searchbox">
  <input type="text" name="q" size="60" value="Search ..." />
  <input type="submit" value="Find it!">
</form>
<div id="result"><div>
<script>
  $("#searchbox").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/more/stuff/here", 
    function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is your html page also located on `http://localhost:8080`? If not, the same-origin-policy is the reason for it.

Comment: Try using Fiddler or Firebug with Firefox to see what result the request returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page that you call in your `$.get` must belong to the same origin (it has been already mentioned here). Moreover, the callback function is called only on success. This means that if you call a page and you are unauthorized (401) or the page cannot be found (404) the callback function will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

It could depends on the same origin policy and eventually on server-side page errors...